# Iterate over pd df with date column by week python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime

I have a one month DataFrame with a datetime object column and a bunch of functions I want to apply to it - by week. So I want to loop over the DataFrame and apply the functions to each week. How do I iterate over weekly time periods?

My DataFrame looks like this: 
[image]

here is some random datetime code:

```
np.random.seed(123)
n = 500
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'date':pd.to_datetime(
                  pd.DataFrame( { 'year':  np.random.choice(range(2017,2019), size=n),
                                  'month': np.random.choice(range(1,2),      size=n),
                                  'day':   np.random.choice(range(1,28),      size=n)
                                 } )
         ) }  
    )
df['random_num'] = np.random.choice(range(0,1000), size=n)
```

My week length is inconsistent (sometimes I have 1000 tweets per week sometimes 100,000). Could please someone give me an example of how to loop over this dataframe by week? (I don't need aggregation or groupby functions.)

Comment: `groupby` is a great way to (even if you do really want to loop) through the resulting DF's of accessing data in a group. Could you elaborate on why you don't need them/aggregation functions? It's always a bit "umm... are you really, really sure" when someone says that's what they want...

Comment: sure. I am applying NLP functions to the tweets and then I am clustering them. I have 6 months data and decided on a k for k-means clustering for each month (doing it for each week would be too time consuming). Now I want to apply the clustering using that k to ever week, so that I can cluster every week of the twitter data. Is it clearer now?

Comment: If your timestamp is a timestamp, you can do `for k, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='W'))` where `k` will be the week and `g` will be a `DataFrame` of items in that week...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't want to use groupby and aggregations then:

```
for week in df['date'].dt.week.unique():
    this_weeks_data = df[df['date'].dt.week == week]
```

This will, of course, go wrong if you have data from more than one year.

Comment: Works fine! That way I could apply all functions and clustering to weekly data.

Answer (score 1):

Given your sample dataframe

```
    date        random_num
0   2017-01-01  214
1   2018-01-19  655
2   2017-01-24  663
3   2017-01-26  723
4   2017-01-01  974
```

First, you can try to set the index to datetime object as follows

```
df.set_index(df.date, inplace=True)
df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This sets the index to the date column and drops the original column. You will get

```
>>> df.head()    
date        random_num
2017-01-01  214
2018-01-19  655
2017-01-24  663
2017-01-26  723
2017-01-01  974
```

Then you can use the pandas `groupby` function to group the data as per your frequency and apply any function of your choice.

```
# To group by week and count the number of occurances
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).count().head()

date        random_num
2017-01-01  11
2017-01-08  65
2017-01-15  55
2017-01-22  66
2017-01-29  45

# To group by week and sum the random numbers per week
>>> df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).sum().head()       

date        random_num
2017-01-01  7132
2017-01-08  33916
2017-01-15  31028
2017-01-22  31509
2017-01-29  22129
```

You can also apply any generic function `myFunction` by using the `apply` method of pandas

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).apply(myFunction)
```

If you want to apply a function `myFunction` to any specific column `columnName` after grouping, you can also do that as follows

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W'))[columnName].apply(myFunction)
```

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED FOR MULTIPLE YEARS]

`pd.Grouper(freq='W')` works fine but sometimes I have come across some undesired behaviors related to how weeks are split when the number of weeks are not even. So this is why I sometimes prefer to do the week split by hand like shown in this example.

So, having a dataset that spans in multiple years

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Create dataset
np.random.seed(123)
n = 100000

date = pd.to_datetime({
    'year': np.random.choice(range(2017, 2020), size=n),
    'month': np.random.choice(range(1, 13), size=n),
    'day': np.random.choice(range(1, 28), size=n)
})

random_num = np.random.choice(
    range(0, 1000),
    size=n)

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'random_num': random_num})
```

Such as:

```
print(df.head())
        date  random_num
0 2019-12-11         413
1 2018-06-08         594
2 2019-08-06         983
3 2019-10-11          73
4 2017-09-19          32
```

First create a helper index that allows you to iterate by week (considering the year as well):

```
df['grp_idx'] = df['date'].apply(
    lambda x: '%s-%s' % (x.year, '{:02d}'.format(x.week)))

print(df.head())
        date  random_num  grp_idx
0 2019-12-11         413  2019-50
1 2018-06-08         594  2018-23
2 2019-08-06         983  2019-32
3 2019-10-11          73  2019-41
4 2017-09-19          32  2017-38
```

Then just apply your function that makes a computation on the weekly-subset, something like this:

```
def something_to_do_by_week(week_data):
    """
    Computes the mean random value.
    """

    return week_data['random_num'].mean()



weekly_mean = df.groupby('grp_idx').apply(something_to_do_by_week)
print(weekly_mean.head())

grp_idx
2017-01    515.875668
2017-02    487.226704
2017-03    503.371681
2017-04    497.717647
2017-05    475.323420
```

Once you have your weekly metrics you'll probably would like to get back to actual dates which are more useful than year-week indices:

```
def from_year_week_to_date(year_week):
    """
    """

    year, week = year_week.split('-')
    year, week = int(year), int(week)

    date = pd.to_datetime('%s-01-01' % year)
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=week * 7)

    return date


weekly_mean.index = [from_year_week_to_date(x) for x in weekly_mean.index]

print(weekly_mean.head())
2017-01-08    515.875668
2017-01-15    487.226704
2017-01-22    503.371681
2017-01-29    497.717647
2017-02-05    475.323420
dtype: float64
```

Finally, now you can make nice plots with nice interpretable dates:
[image]

Just as a sanity check, the computation using `pd.Grouper(freq='W')` gives me almost the same results (somehow it adds an extra week at the beginning of the pd.Series)

```
df.set_index('date').groupby(
    pd.Grouper(freq='W')
).mean().head()
Out[27]: 
            random_num
date                  
2017-01-01  532.736364
2017-01-08  515.875668
2017-01-15  487.226704
2017-01-22  503.371681
2017-01-29  497.717647
```